# I accidentally moved a directory to '..'. Where did it go?

Tags: directory, mv

I accidently left a trailing slash on my directory name when renaming a folder in Linux,

```
mv /images/images/ ..
```

Now the folder has vanished, But I know it's still there due to the space it's using, I'm thinking it's renamed to '..' but I cannot seem to rename it back? Anyone know the answer? :)

Comment: I know that in Unix file terms, **..** (dot dot) refers to the parent directory. To see this, run: `ls -a` I'm not certain what implications this has.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: What directory you where when you moved the directory and.. was it filled with stuff?

Comment: this would have moved images (last directory) up one level. If you were in / (root) . and .. are equivalent, this would have moved images to /

Answer (score 1):

`..` denotes the parent directory. Suppose you are in the `home/user/TEST` folder, where there is the `images1/images2` directory. Then you have now a `images2` folder in `home/user/` and an `images1` folder in `TEST`, without the subdirectory `images2`:

```
~$ mkdir TEST
~$ cd TEST
~/TEST$ mkdir -p images1/images2
~/TEST$ touch images1/images2/a_file
~/TEST$ mv images1/images2/ ..
fti@erebe:~/TEST$ ls images1
fti@erebe:~/TEST$ ls ..
images2  TEST
fti@erebe:~/TEST$ ls ../images2/
a_file
```

---

I didn't see the first slash in `/images/images`.
As you were in the root folder (`/`), and since root folder doesn't have a parent directory, `/..` is the same as `/` so you move `/images/images` to (`/..`)`/images`. In other words, a file in `/images/images/foo.txt` should now be in `/images/foo.txt`.

Comment: I don't have this, in your code your mv images1/images2 .. is what I wanted to do, but i actually put mv images1/images2/ .. (trailing slash) now I can't find the folder

Comment: The trailing slash shouldn't matter.

Comment: Well I'm using Centos 6 and the folder isn't visible since I moved it with trailing slash. I've done ls -a and cannot see in the directory above :(

Comment: try `ls -a ..` to see the parent directory

Comment: it's not there either

Comment: and you didn't change you working directory? (using `cd` or `cd something`) Do you see the `images1` folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19386/discussion-between-ricky-odin-matthews-and-fredtantini).

Answer (score 1):

`mv /images/images/ ..` moves the directory called `images` from the directory `/images` into the parent directory of the *current directory*.

The *current directory* is whichever directory you were in at the time you ran the `mv` command. Your directory will not have "disappeared". You just need to work out where you were when you ran the `mv` command, and from there find the parent.

P.S. `mv /images/images ..` (without the trailing `/`) would have done exactly the same thing if `/images/images` is (or was) a directory. The only difference you would have seen in behaviour by adding a slash would be to force the `mv` command to fail if `/images/images` turned out to be a file instead of a directory.

Comment: Note that if working out of a symlinked directory, the parent will be the parent of the source directory.